# meaning of "There does tend to be"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the meaning of **tend** and **there is** but I cannot get exact meaning and grammatical rule of **there does tend to be** in the following sentence:

> In applied mathematics (mechanics, statistics, decision mathematics, and so on), **there does tend to be** more focus on solving problems and less on developing abstract theories. (source: *How to Study for a Mathematics Degree* by Lara Alcock)

-----Edit (clarifying my question)

What is the difference between the following forms in meaning and what are the grammatical structure of the sentences?

1. **There is** more focus on solving problems.
2. **There tends to be** more focus on solving problems.
3. **There does tend to be** more focus on solving problems.

Comment: By the way, this sentence is from the book "how to study for a mathematics degree" by lara alcock .

Comment: Thanks for telling us the source in a comment. Next time, please include that information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the thing/phenomenon/result **is generally the case**.

More often than not, something is true.
It can be widely observed that ......
There is broad agreement that.......

There does tend to be more rain in summer than winter.
There does tend to be more casual work in spring.
There does tend to be a lot of noise from the main road.

Answer (score 1):

If something 'tends' towards a particular result, it means that, *more often than not* that is the case.

Presenting data that shows *trends* and *tendencies* is often very credible and can support a theory or a statement. However, as tendencies are not a strict rule, you will find that people put them across in a variety of ways depending on how solidly they think it proves what they are saying.

> "In applied mathematics, *there tends to be* more focus on solving problems and less on developing abstract theories."

This means that that, in the field of mathematics, emphasis is placed *more often than not* on problem solving than developing abstract theories.

Notice that, in your quotation, it says "there *does* tend to be". This is a more gingerly way of putting the same statement across, and may be that the writer wanted to be slightly non-committal so as not to exclude the exceptions. Saying "there does tend to be" places emphasis on the observed results.